# Select Rows with values that exceed a specific threshold

Tags: mysql, grafana

The following table shows the latitude position at different time stamps. [Latitude Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUYk0.png)

[Latitude Table][2]

To build a table with only latitude points above 42 be returned,I tried the following
but an error pops up:

ValidationException: The query syntax is invalid at line 3:96

```
SELECT * FROM (

  SELECT * FROM $__database.$__table WHERE measure_name  = 'Latitude (deg)' > 42  ORDER BY measure_name DESC
 
) AS r ORDER BY r.measure_name ASC
```

EDIT :

```
Vessel|Uploaded On| measure_name|time     |measure_value::double
Ran | 20:59:07 | Latitude (deg)| 18:55:00 | 43.7
Ran | 21:04:07 | Latitude (deg)| 19:00:00 | 41.6
Ran | 20:09:07 | Latitude (deg)| 19:05:00 | 44.5
Ran | 20:14:17 | Latitude (deg)| 19:10:00 | 40.2
Ran | 20:19:07 | Latitude (deg)| 19:15:00 | 43.2
```

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Also, show schema for the table; especially what are the data type of the various relevant columns

Comment: can you share the column types?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a reference to the *measure_value* column in your `WHERE` clause comparisons. This is a compound predicate, and both columns need to be included in order for the SQL to compile.

It should be:

```
WHERE measure_name = 'Latitude (deg)'
    AND measure_value > 42.0
```